# Data clustering with multiple observations for one subject in R

Tags: r, clustering

I have the following data frame:

```
   ID      NLR1  NLR_CHANGE
2   2 3.7941176 -2.10364146
3   3 0.4871245  0.21313393
4   3 0.5225653  0.10084435
5   3 0.6386364  1.41399522
6   3 0.7134269 -0.07937597
9   3 0.6800000 -0.22620123
10  3 0.6529412  0.09188641
11  3 0.6825939  0.35989906
14  5 0.8073654 -0.06175140
15  4 0.4404332  0.35474751
16  6 2.0184049 -0.98033384
17  7 1.1020408  0.96307546
20  9 2.7012195 -0.78349799
21  9 1.7093023  0.37799926
22  9 1.6756757 -0.53281853
23 11 1.5867508 -0.70991794
24 12 2.5789474 -1.00653358
25 13 0.6109325  0.20881001
26 14 2.2857143  0.42857143
27 15 1.8472222 -0.34325397
```

Each line is a separate observation, but each subject often has more than one observation. For this reason, I assume that individual observations may be strongly dependent on each other.

However, due to the fact that the number of measurements for individual subjects varies greatly and the measurements were taken at irregular intervals, I probably cannot treat these data as ordinary longitudinal data.

I would like to do a cluster analysis using k-means or k-medoids, but due to the above, I don't think I can use for example a package like `kml`.

I have 50 observations and 28 subjects. If I exclude subjects who have only 1 observation, I have 31 observations and 10 subjects.

What kind of methods or packages could I use to cluster this kind of data?

EDIT: I will try to describe the problem in more detail. The variable NLR was measured twice at different time intervals during each observation. I conducted an analysis using a linear mixed-effect model (lmer function) in which the test variable was the change between the first and second of these measurements. The model works fine. Knowing the NLR value of the first measurement, it is possible to predict with satisfactory accuracy how it will change in the second measurement. The higher the NLR in the first measurement, the greater the decrease in the second.

I have found that individual subjects usually follow a similar pattern of observation. If in one observation the NLR was very low (and thus there was a small change in NLR to its second measurement within the same observation), then probably the NLR was also low in other observations of the same subject.

Moreover, in subjects with low NLR, it does not increase with time, i.e. in subsequent observations. In contrast to subjects with high NLR, in which the NLR decreases significantly not only within the observation, but also increases in subsequent observations. It seems likely that there is a group of subjects that exhibit a relatively low variability in the NLR - both within observation and long-term.

I would like to determine whether it is possible to determine in which NLR subjects show high variability, and in which low variability, on the basis of additional data, such as gender, smoking and so on.

Comment: It is unclear: is your goal to cluster subjects or to cluster observations?

Comment: I want to cluster observations with „adjustment” for similarities within subject.

Comment: It is not enough clear what kind of adjustment you have in mind. One way might be just to include column ID into clustering. (But it is categorical, therefore you won't be able to do specifically k-means.) This assumes that observations belonging to same subject are apriori "more similar".

Comment: What is the "adjustment" meant to achieve? Generally, clustering depends on what meaning the clusters are supposed to have, and what they are used for. Do you want observations from the same subject to cluster together? Do you want them to cluster together if they are enough similar but maybe not quite as similar as observations from different subjects have to be in order to be together in a cluster? You need to specify more clearly the role that the subject information should play. The pure data cannot decide this on their own.

Comment: I will try to describe the problem in more detail. The variable NLR was measured twice at different time intervals during each observation. I conducted an analysis using a linear mixed-effect model (lmer function) in which the test variable was the change between the first and second of these measurements. The model works fine. Knowing the NLR value of the first measurement, it is possible to predict with satisfactory accuracy how it will change in the second measurement. The higher the NLR in the first measurement, the greater the decrease in the second.

Comment: I have found that individual subjects usually follow a similar pattern of observation. If in one observation the NLR was very low (and thus there was a small change in NLR to its second measurement within the same observation), then probably the NLR was also low in other observations of the same subject. Moreover, in subjects with low NLR, it does not increase with time, i.e. in subsequent observations. In contrast to subjects with high NLR, in which the NLR decreases significantly not only within the observation, but also increases in subsequent observations.

Comment: It seems likely that there is a group of subjects that exhibit a relatively low variability in the NLR - both within observation and long-term. I would like to determine whether it is possible to determine in which NLR subjects show high variability, and in which low variability, on the basis of additional data, such as gender, smoking and so on.